# Javascript/HTML, Change multiple DIV content depending on DIV text. (Codepen)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to change the DIV background image and text depending on the text of the DIV initially. It works when i do with 1 DIV, but it does not when i do multiple DIV's. How can i do it with multiple DIV's? Thank you.

HTML

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>


<div class="BackI" style="height: 250px; width: 250px;">6,Background Image1-</div>
<div class="BackI" style="height: 250px; width: 250px;">99,Background Image2-</div>
<div class="BackI" style="height: 250px; width: 250px;">9,Background Image3-</div>
```

JS

```
$(function() {
var text = $('.BackI').text().toLowerCase();
var str1 = text.split(',');

switch (str1[0]) {
  case '6':
    image = 'http://cdn.mysitemyway.com/etc-mysitemyway/icons/legacy-previews/icons-256/matte-grey-square-icons-symbols-shapes/120234-matte-grey-square-icon-symbols-shapes-tile.png';
    break;
  case '99':
    image = 'http://cdn.mysitemyway.com/etc-mysitemyway/icons/legacy-previews/icons-256/matte-red-and-white-square-icons-symbols-shapes/124116-matte-red-and-white-square-icon-symbols-shapes-tile.png';
    break;
   case '9':
    image = 'http://cdn.mysitemyway.com/etc-mysitemyway/icons/legacy-previews/icons-256/matte-blue-and-white-square-icons-symbols-shapes/118294-matte-blue-and-white-square-icon-symbols-shapes-tile1-ps.png';
    break;
  default:
    image = '';
}
$('.BackI').css({
  'background-image': 'url(' + image + ')'
}).text(str1[1]);
  });
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yYQVgQ  Code in codepen.io

Comment: `$.each()` is a great hint

Answer (score 4):

Use `.each()` to loop through each element.

[jQuery documentation link](https://api.jquery.com/each/)

```js
$(function() {
  $('.BackI').each(function() {
    var text = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
    var str1 = text.split(',');

    switch (str1[0]) {
      case '6':
        image = 'http://cdn.mysitemyway.com/etc-mysitemyway/icons/legacy-previews/icons-256/matte-grey-square-icons-symbols-shapes/120234-matte-grey-square-icon-symbols-shapes-tile.png';
        break;
      case '99':
        image = 'http://cdn.mysitemyway.com/etc-mysitemyway/icons/legacy-previews/icons-256/matte-red-and-white-square-icons-symbols-shapes/124116-matte-red-and-white-square-icon-symbols-shapes-tile.png';
        break;
      case '9':
        image = 'http://cdn.mysitemyway.com/etc-mysitemyway/icons/legacy-previews/icons-256/matte-blue-and-white-square-icons-symbols-shapes/118294-matte-blue-and-white-square-icon-symbols-shapes-tile1-ps.png';
        break;
      default:
        image = '';
    }
    $(this).css({
      'background-image': 'url(' + image + ')'
    }).text(str1[1]);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js">
</script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>


<div class="BackI" style="height: 250px; width: 250px;">6,Background Image1-</div>
<div class="BackI" style="height: 250px; width: 250px;">99,Background Image2-</div>
<div class="BackI" style="height: 250px; width: 250px;">9,Background Image3-</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have problem with selector. Try like this,

```
$(".BackI").each( function(){
   var text = $(this).text()...

   $(this).css()...
})
```

Answer (score 0):

> Get the combined text contents of each element in the set of matched elements, including their descendants, or set the text contents of the matched elements.

You function getting called one time and the value of str1 is the combined result of all text-Elements and splittet by the first "," it is 6. You have to call your function for each div.

Answer (score 0):

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/ux88bng2/

```
$('.BackI').each(function () {
    var text = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
    var str1 = text.split(',');
    switch (str1[0]) {
        case '6':
            image = 'http://cdn.mysitemyway.com/etc-mysitemyway/icons/legacy-previews/icons-256/matte-grey-square-icons-symbols-shapes/120234-matte-grey-square-icon-symbols-shapes-tile.png';
            break;
        case '99':
            image = 'http://cdn.mysitemyway.com/etc-mysitemyway/icons/legacy-previews/icons-256/matte-red-and-white-square-icons-symbols-shapes/124116-matte-red-and-white-square-icon-symbols-shapes-tile.png';
            break;
        case '9':
            image = 'http://cdn.mysitemyway.com/etc-mysitemyway/icons/legacy-previews/icons-256/matte-blue-and-white-square-icons-symbols-shapes/118294-matte-blue-and-white-square-icon-symbols-shapes-tile1-ps.png';
            break;
        default:
            image = '';
    }
    $(this).css({
        'background-image': 'url(' + image + ')'
    }).text(str1[1]);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

While the other answers are all correct, I would recommend this one:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>


<div class="BackI" style="height: 250px; width: 250px;" data-image_number=6 >Background Image1</div>
<div class="BackI" style="height: 250px; width: 250px;" data-image_number=99 >Background Image2</div>
<div class="BackI" style="height: 250px; width: 250px;" data-image_number=9 >Background Image3</div>

$(function() {
    $('[data-image_number]').each(function(){
        var image_number = $(this).attr('data-image_number');
        switch (image_number) {
          case '6':
            image = 'http://cdn.mysitemyway.com/etc-mysitemyway/icons/legacy-previews/icons-256/matte-grey-square-icons-symbols-shapes/120234-matte-grey-square-icon-symbols-shapes-tile.png';
            break;
          case '99':
            image = 'http://cdn.mysitemyway.com/etc-mysitemyway/icons/legacy-previews/icons-256/matte-red-and-white-square-icons-symbols-shapes/124116-matte-red-and-white-square-icon-symbols-shapes-tile.png';
            break;
           case '9':
            image = 'http://cdn.mysitemyway.com/etc-mysitemyway/icons/legacy-previews/icons-256/matte-blue-and-white-square-icons-symbols-shapes/118294-matte-blue-and-white-square-icon-symbols-shapes-tile1-ps.png';
            break;
          default:
            image = '';
            break;
        }

        if(image)
            $(this).css({
              'background-image': 'url(' + image + ')'
            });
    });
});
```

It's much simpler to use html custom data elements and attributes instead of having it in the html and parsing it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your solution :

```
$(function() {
    $(".BackI").each( function(){
        var text = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
        var str1 = text.split(',');

        switch (str1[0]) {
          case '6':
          image = 'http://cdn.mysitemyway.com/etc-mysitemyway/icons/legacy-previews/icons-256/matte-grey-square-icons-symbols-shapes/120234-matte-grey-square-icon-symbols-shapes-tile.png';
          break;
          case '99':
          image = 'http://cdn.mysitemyway.com/etc-mysitemyway/icons/legacy-previews/icons-256/matte-red-and-white-square-icons-symbols-shapes/124116-matte-red-and-white-square-icon-symbols-shapes-tile.png';
          break;
          case '9':
          image = 'http://cdn.mysitemyway.com/etc-mysitemyway/icons/legacy-previews/icons-256/matte-blue-and-white-square-icons-symbols-shapes/118294-matte-blue-and-white-square-icon-symbols-shapes-tile1-ps.png';
          break;
          default:
          image = '';
      }

      $(this).css({'background-image': 'url(' + image + ')'}).text(str1[1]);

  });

});
```